# For a power series function that is constantly zero prove that the coefficients are zero

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

> Suppose that power series function $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + ...$
>   is constantly zero on a bounded non-empty open interval $I$, which may or may not contain $0$.
>
> > Prove that $a_j = 0$ for every $j$, so that the power series is constantly zero on its whole domain (which is of course centered at $0$).

Here is my thought: let us call power series function given in the problem $f$. Let
$I = (a, b)$ (where $a < b$, of course), and let $c= (a+b)/2=$ the center of $I$. 
I don't know how to go from here. Any help?

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 6 questions in two days. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 1):

**Complex analytic solution**:

$f$ is a power series, so it is analytic. Since $f$ is $0$ in a uncountable set, it agrees with $0$ everywhere in its domain.

**Real analytic solution**:

There exists a unique set of coefficients $(b_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ such that
$$ f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j (x - c)^j = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(c)}{j!} (x - c)^j
$$
Since the derivatives of $f$ at $c$ are all $0$, all $b_j = 0$. $f$ is a power series, so $(a_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ is a unique set of coefficients so that
$$ \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j = \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j (x-c)^j
$$
and it turns out that $a_j = 0$.

Comment: You have to justify why you can use the identity principle, however.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks. It is fixed.

Comment: I havent done any complex analysis. Can you explain the first step a little more?

Comment: @THT16224 The first way uses the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement). It is justified since every power series is analytic (a.k.a. holomorphic)

Comment: I meant the first step in the real analytic way

Comment: @THT16224 The coefficients $(b_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ are unique since they are defined by $\frac{f^{(j)}(c)}{j!}$.

Comment: Okay I see that now. And how do you make the move to the second/final step. I am trying to understand but I am missing it

Comment: @THT16224 $b_j = \frac{0}{j!} = 0$. The part for $a_j$ follows from uniqueness of power series.

Comment: Hmm okay. I still think I don't completely understand it. But I appreciate it

Comment: The whole question is whether the $(b_j)$ are unique, so referring to uniqueness is begging the question!