# Proof That A Power Series Only Equals Zero If and Only If Its Coefficients Equal Zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

I've heard it said that a power series equals zero iff all of its coefficients equal zero.

That is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^n=0\quad\iff\quad a_i =0\quad \forall i \;\in \Bbb{N}$$

Comment: If you are dealing with *formal* power series then the result is true by definition. If you are dealing with "functions" in power-series form, then the matter is more involved.

Comment: I don't know.  It's mentioned in this video around the 5:15 mark.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYJq3mhg5yE&index=18&list=PLkZjai-2Jcxkgr0Y2yFfWiMFbKKbBXPTK