# Comparing coefficients in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the following expression:

$-\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{u_0-1}{u_0}\right)^nnE_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{u_0-1}{u_0}\right)^n\left(E_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha)-\sum_{j=0}^n E_\alpha(-(n-j)k^\alpha t^\alpha)E_\alpha(-j k^\alpha t^\alpha)\right),$

where $\alpha \in (0,1), t \geq 0, k \text{ is a constant} \text{ and } E_\alpha(z) = \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha m + 1)} \text{ is the Mittag Leffler function.}$

In a paper I'm studying, the author conclude from this, the following:

$$(n+1)E_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha) = \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n E_\alpha(-(n-j)k^\alpha t^\alpha)E_\alpha(-j k^\alpha t^\alpha)$$

I don't know how he concludes this. I suspect they used some property involving equality of series with the coefficients.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Greetings: It is usually inadvisable to say "I've read this in a paper and..." without also mentioning the citation for the paper. Quite often it is important context and you do not want to hamstring your readers by keeping it to yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your expression

$-\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{u_0-1}{u_0}\right)^nnE_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{u_0-1}{u_0}\right)^n\left(E_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha)-\sum_{j=0}^n E_\alpha(-(n-j)k^\alpha t^\alpha)E_\alpha(-j k^\alpha t^\alpha)\right),$

Compare the coefficient of $\left(\frac{u_0-1}{u_0}\right)^n$ on both sides, then you'll get

$$-nE_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha) = E_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha)-\sum_{j=0}^n E_\alpha(-(n-j)k^\alpha t^\alpha)E_\alpha(-j k^\alpha t^\alpha),$$

which rearranges to your desired

$$(n+1)E_\alpha(-nk^\alpha t^\alpha) = \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n E_\alpha(-(n-j)k^\alpha t^\alpha)E_\alpha(-j k^\alpha t^\alpha).$$

Comment: I was thinking that these properties only work if the coefficients of the series are all positive.

Can you give a reference?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389280/prove-if-a-power-series-is-zero-on-an-interval-then-all-coefficients-are-zero) will help

Comment: Thank you! Based on your post, if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ converges for $|x| \leq 1$ and for some $c \in (0,1]$ we have 
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n x^n  = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n x^n = 0, \forall |x| < c
$$
then we can conclude that $a_n = b_n$.

Comment: But in my case, if we denote 
$$
a_n = -n E_{\alpha}(-nk^{\alpha}t^{\alpha})
$$
and
$$
b_n = E_{\alpha}(-nk^{\alpha}t^{\alpha}) - \sum_{j=0}^{n} E_{\alpha}(-(n-j)k^{\alpha}t^{\alpha}) E_{\alpha}(-j k ^{\alpha} t^{\alpha})
$$
we'd conclude, for $x_0 = \frac{u_0 - 1}{u_0}$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_0^{n} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_0^{n} b_n .
$$
I actually dont have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n} b_n $ for any small $x$.

Comment: Really? How fast does $E_\alpha$ grow? I thought $\frac{u_0-1}{u_0} = 1 - 1/u_0$. From your context, can you assume $u_0 \in [1,\infty)$?